# how to retrieve multiple keys in firebase with forloop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, firebase

Considering this data structure, i want to fetch the keys encircled. here is my example code but it returns only the attributes used of the child of each keys

```
sampletry=firebase.database().ref("users");
sampletry.on("value",function(snap){
    var groupData = snap.val();
    for(var groupID in groupData){
            var yeah = Object.keys(groupData[groupID]);
            console.log(yeah);
    }
})
```

[sample structure of keys that needs to be retrieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blvom.jpg)

Comment: `var yeah = groupID`

Comment: ohhhh got it thanks loki. is there any better way to do it?

Comment: can i ask another question loki? what if i want to get all data for a certain key only? example i want to get all data for this key -L1c4Jc2qGCE45JKuuC2? how do i structure that?

Comment: sampletry1=firebase.database().ref("users").child("-L1c4Jc2qGCE45JKuuC2"); got it! thanks again loki :)

Comment: to access data of each key u just need to do groupData[groupId] which you are already doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example which is somewhat similar to your situation
 `var keyStore = {
        firstKey: {
                type: 'normal',
                count: 15
            },
        secondKey: {
                type: 'exclusive',
                count: 2
            }

    };
    for (var key in keyStore) {
        console.log('Key name: ', key);
        console.log('Key Data: ', keyStore[key]);
    }`

Comment: i thought it would just return the key itself depending on the constraint. but i printed the return value of snap.val in console and it returns together with the data . thanks again :)

Comment: happy to help. I have no idea about firebase or jquery much. Tried simulating your thing in javascript and help you with it.

Comment: also if you find the answer useful accept it so that the unanswered questions gets reduced.